# Show autocomplete only after 3 entered chars in <datalist> field?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to autocomplete only after a user entered at least 3 letters?
Here is my current code:

HTML/PHP:

```
<form name="form" class="form-container" method="post" onsubmit="return doValidate()" id="myForm2">
  <label>
    <input placeholder="Organisator" id="name" list="users" name="mitarbeiter" required />
  </label> 
  <datalist id="users" class="dle" >
    <?php
      for ($i=0; $i<$counts; $i++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$AllData[$i]["mail"][0].'">'.$AllData[$i]["cn"][0].'</option>'; 
      }
    ?>
  </datalist>
  <br><br>
  von 
  <input type="time" name="zeitstart" class="zeitangaben" id="startzeitid"> Uhr bis 
  <input type="time" name="zeitende" id="endzeitid" class="zeitangaben"> Uhr <br><br> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Reservierung erstellen</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn cancel" onclick="hideDiv()">Abbrechen</button>
</form>
```

I only find some Code with Jquery, is it not possible to do this without jquery?

Is it even possible? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by autocomplete? What do you want to auto complete? An organisator's name? Does the auto complete has to fetch the organisator's names in your database? Show more details.

Comment: @AlexisPhilip Yes, the datalist Shows Organisators names from my database. The User just Need to write 1 letter and the datalist automaticly Displays some names. But I want that datalist only Show names when the user has entered at least 3 letter.

Comment: I provided a working example in the answer below. Is it working for you? If it did, you could accept the answer with the check mark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to do it: **removing the `datalist` `ID` attribute**.

First, declare the `querySelector()` methods.

```
var input    = document.querySelector("#name"), // Selects the input.
    datalist = document.querySelector("datalist"); // Selects the datalist.
```

Then declare the `addEventListener` method on the `input` element.

```
// Adds a keyup listener on the input.
input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {

    // If input value is longer or equal than 2 chars, adding "users" on ID attribute.
    if (e.target.value.length >= 2) {
        datalist.setAttribute("id", "users");
    } else {
        datalist.setAttribute("id", "");
    }
});
```

***Explanation***

When the input value has a length greater than or equal to 2, the `setAttribute()` method sets the `datalist` `ID` attribute to `"users"`.

I set the operator to `>= 2` and not `>= 3`. Here is why: the `datalist` dropdown element is triggered at each keypress.

The process goes like this:

1. `length == 1` `id=""` - The drop down is not displayed, no `ID` is linked to the `datalist`;
2. `length == 2` `id="users"` - The drop down is not displayed, then `datalist` has its `ID` set to `"users"`;
3. `length == 3` `id="users"` - The drop down now reads that the `ID` is set to `"users"` and displays the drop down.

***Cons***

- Since the attribute is set when the input length is `>= 2`, if the input length `== 3`, the attribute will be removed when the input length `== 2`, and the drop down will be hidden when the input length `== 1`.
- Since the drop down list is part of the `OS` and is not a `DOM`
  element, it cannot be styled (or hidden, in this case). This is why I
  used the `setAttribute()` method to set or remove the `ID`.

***Upgrade?***

A great upgrade / perfect solution would be creating a dropdown in `JS` just under the input. The drop down would be DOM element, and you could style it the way you want. You could ealisy display it `> 2` chars and hide it `< 3` chars.

***Snippet***

```js
var input    = document.querySelector("#name"), // Selects the input.
    datalist = document.querySelector("datalist"); // Selects the datalist.

// Adds a keyup listener on the input.
input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {

    // If input value is larger or equal than 2 chars, adding "users" on ID attribute.
    if (e.target.value.length >= 2) {
        datalist.setAttribute("id", "users");
    } else {
        datalist.setAttribute("id", "");
    }
});

// I had to include your doValidate() function otherwise I would get an error while validaing.
function doValidate() {};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>reading json</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">function log(p) {return console.log(p)}</script>
</head>
<body>


<form name="form" class="form-container" method="post" onsubmit="return doValidate()" id="myForm2">

    <label><input placeholder="Organisator" id="name" list="users" name="mitarbeiter" autocomplete='off' required /></label>
    <datalist id="users" class="dle">
        <option value="alicia@keys.com">Alicia Keys</option>
        <option value="alicia@keyssecond.com">Alicia The Second</option>
        <option value="john@doe.com">John Doe</option>
        <option value="martin@scorsese.com">Martin Scorsese</option>
        <option value="iron@man.com">Iron Man</option>
    </datalist><br><br>

    von <input type="time" name="zeitstart" class="zeitangaben" id="startzeitid"> Uhr bis <input type="time" name="zeitende" id="endzeitid" class="zeitangaben"> Uhr <br><br> 

<button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Reservierung erstellen</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn cancel" onclick="hideDiv()">Abbrechen</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's almost what I want. I want the names that appear after 3 letters in the suggestions.
Currently the name appears below the input field and the suggestions are already indicated after the user entered one letter. This will be my answer if you can change it. :)

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question. Here is a new answer :)

Comment: I had a similar solution, but it suffered from the same issue as this: it only works one way.
If I type SEC, only Alicia the Second appears. But if I hit backspace leaving only SE, Martin Scorsese appears.
This is not an issue in this toy example, but in my case I have a list of 500-1000 article codes so I really want the minLength to persist.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use javascript and listen to the `keyup` event for your input element.

Then you check if the value of the input is longer than 3 character and if it is, you need to make an ajax request to your server to get the related names and use them to fill the `datalist`

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd share what I did using `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` on the `keyUp` and `keyDown` to display the datalist (`dir`) when the text box contains at least 3 characters and handling the Backspace (`keyCode=8`) to prevent the full list from showing as it widens the search results.

```html
<input type="search" name="q" id="q" autofocus="true"
       onkeyup="if(this.value.length>=3)this.setAttribute('list','dir');" 
       onkeydown="if(this.value.length<3||event.keyCode==8)this.removeAttribute('list');"
       placeholder="Search Staff Directory"
/>
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for a simple solution that does not require jQuery or Ajax, just a simple datalist.