# Javascript how to make auto suggest results appear after entering 3 characters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an `array` with cars like this:

```
[
  {"name" : "Audi"},
  {"name" : "BMW"},
  {"name" : "Mercedes"}, 
  {"name" : "VW"},
  {"name" : "Fiat"},
  {"name" : "Hyundai"},
  {"name" : "Opel"},
  ...and many many more
]
```

now I have an input field, where users can search for their desired car but I want to include some auto-suggest. So far I have made this

```
<input type="text" @input="filterCars" v-model="search" />


filterSkills() {
  this.filterCars = this.cars.filter(car => {
    return car.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
  });
}
```

which actually works fine, but I want to make the matching results appear, after the user has **entered 3 characters** - for example, when I type 'Aud' - Audi will appear as suggestion - how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204605/2972052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter only when length is desired length or more, if it's less return an empty array therefore clearing the list:

```
filterSkills() {
    this.filterCars = this.search.length > 2 ? this.cars.filter(car => 
    car.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())) : [];
}
```

Comment: This is pretty nice and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition in your filterSkills function

```
filterSkills() {
   if (this.search.length >= 3) {
    this.filterCars = this.cars.filter(car => {
      return car.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
    });
   }else{
     return [];
   }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hey you can do onething,
```

```
 **onInputChange(text) {
   if (*here you can put the condition if text has atleset 3 alphabets like this.search.length>3*) {
       filteredData = this.options[0].data.filter(item => {
     return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }).slice(0, this.limit);
   }**
```